# Clarification on writing MSMQ 4.0 message consumer application?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, msmq

I need to write an application (not a sevrice or web service) that consumes messages from an MSMQ 4.0 queue and want to make use of 4.0's features such as poison message handling.  I see a lot of examples of WCF Services to consume messages from MSMQ queues, for example http://www.devx.com/enterprise/Article/39015, is this the sort of thing I need to be doing or is there a different way of handling MSMQ queues in applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some [documentation and sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395218.aspx) on Poison Message Handling in MSMQ 4.0 . I don't think that there is a major difference in this case, if you are creating a desktop application  and not a service.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [.Net library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx), a [COM lbrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926129.aspx) and a [win32 library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919574.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Lars.  I've looked at the .Net library (since I'm using C#) but I couldn't see any way to configure or activate posion messaging handling or how to redirect messages to a dead letter queue short of pulling them off and posting them to it in my own app.  Any ideas on that?